# Why this vue component doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel 5.7.
I am using a vue component in my view, i followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvo4GwVxz_Q).

this tag is in my create.blade.php and it works fine.

```
<slug-widget url="{{url('/')}}" subdirectory="blog" :title="title" @slug-changed="updateSlug"></slug-widget>
```

in my app.js i have

```
Vue.component('slugWidget', require('./components/slugWidget.vue'));
```

So as you see i'm not using this inside of app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
 });
```

The slugWidget.vue is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesmva/2c04eshw/)

inside of my create.blade.php i have a script

```
@section('scripts')
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        title: '',
        slug: '',
        api_token: '{{Auth::user()->api_token}}'
      },
      methods: {
        updateSlug: function(val) {
          this.slug = val;
        }
      }
    });        
  </script>
@endsection
```

The problem is that i'm not getting vue right, i'm noob at it.
I am trying to add a new component, so i'm trying to test the example-component
that comes with laravel.
Inside the app.js i'm using

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
```

In my create.blade.php i am using `<example-component></example-component>`
I get this error:

**[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

Do i have to add something inside the script in create.blade.php?
The only script i have is for the slug-widget.
What i'm doing wrong and please explain so i can learn to make my own components.

Comment: change it from `Vue.component('slugWidget', require('./components/slugWidget.vue'));` to this: `Vue.component('slug-widget', require('./components/slugWidget.vue'));`

Comment: @DerekPollard what about the exmple-component?

Comment: Try clearing the browsers catch.